# Error when building the project in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I get following error while building the project.

Clening also didn't help. No idea what went wrong all of a sudden

```
CompileAssetCatalog /Users/Mayu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pizza_to_Go-dohdzfdfbyycqrhirbysuinqfuzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pizza\ to\ Go.app Pizza\ to\ Go/Images.xcassets Pizza\ to\ Go/Images.xcassets
    cd "/Users/Mayu/Documents/development/git/pizzatogo/iPhoneApp/Pizza to Go"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/Mayu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pizza_to_Go-dohdzfdfbyycqrhirbysuinqfuzf/Build/Intermediates/Pizza\ to\ Go.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pizza\ to\ Go.build/assetcatalog_dependencies.txt --output-partial-info-plist /Users/Mayu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pizza_to_Go-dohdzfdfbyycqrhirbysuinqfuzf/Build/Intermediates/Pizza\ to\ Go.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pizza\ to\ Go.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --launch-image LaunchImage --platform iphonesimulator --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --target-device iphone --compress-pngs --compile /Users/Mayu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pizza_to_Go-dohdzfdfbyycqrhirbysuinqfuzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pizza\ to\ Go.app /Users/Mayu/Documents/development/git/pizzatogo/iPhoneApp/Pizza\ to\ Go/Pizza\ to\ Go/Images.xcassets /Users/Mayu/Documents/development/git/pizzatogo/iPhoneApp/Pizza\ to\ Go/Pizza\ to\ Go/Images.xcassets

/* com.apple.actool.errors */
: error: There are multiple app icon set instances named "AppIcon".
: error: There are multiple launch image set instances named "LaunchImage".
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/Mayu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pizza_to_Go-dohdzfdfbyycqrhirbysuinqfuzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pizza to Go.app/Assets.car
/Users/Mayu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pizza_to_Go-dohdzfdfbyycqrhirbysuinqfuzf/Build/Intermediates/Pizza to Go.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pizza to Go.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As this error says you have duplicated images AppIcon and LaunchImage. To sort it just make copy of it and remove it from your project (have a look in Images.xcassets and remove it as well). After that import it again to Images.xcassets.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find these images. I dleted the 'images.xcassets' and regenerated using the project's page (change from do not use asset catelog. Now I have a backup but where to find those images to delete in first place?

Comment: I believe you removed reference to the project with image.xcassets. Go directly to the project directory (finder) and copy it from there. After that remove it and add it again via Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the problem was that I had my assets folder with multiple targets with while extensions already had those target assigned. Fix was to make sure each asset folder was only assigned to its specific target, or delete folders that are not needed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Error:** multiple instances of AppIcon (when working with Storyboard).

**This solution worked for me:**

Look in the Storyboard window's Navigation panel for a duplicate listing of Images.xcassets.  If there, highlight it and press delete key.  When asked, select “remove reference” - not send to trash (which might delete the actual Images.xcassets folder). Apparently this duplicate listing in the project can occur if an attempt is aborted to import something into Images.xcassetes.